# "Agree on Terms"-checkbox

Tags: php, html

How would you create a Agree on Terms...-checkbox to a `<button>`... and not an `<input>`...?

I see everyone uses a `<input type="checkmark"...>` that has a working Terms-checkbox to a `<input type="submit"...>`

How do I get such checkbox with this code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_user">Register</button>
```

What I have found that uses `<input>` is:

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="if(document.getElementById('agree').checked) { return true; } else { alert('Please indicate that you have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy'); return false; }">

   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" /> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />

</form>
```

SOLUTION:

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="if(document.getElementById('agree').checked) { return true; } else { alert('Please indicate that you have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy'); return false; }">
    <input type="checkbox" required name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" /> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy
    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_user">Register</button>
</form>
```

Adding "required": `<input type="checkbox" required name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" />` made everything work.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve visually? For example WHY must you want to use `button` instead of `input` ?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use `required` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" required name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" />
```

Comment: He wants to use `<button>`

Comment: Does that bypass the regular html5 form validation?